# How to resize MATLAB matrix

Tags: matlab

If I have matrix `size(mat)= X*Y*6`

let call  `mat(:,:,1)=A`

and `mat(:,:,2)=B`  and so on

how do i rezise mat to X*Y*12

where

```
mat(:,:,1)=mat(:,:,2)= A
mat(:,:,3)=mat(:,:,4)=B
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
%defines input matrix (in your case it is already defined)
m = 500;
n = 400;
z = 6;
mat = rand(m,n,z); 

%initialize output matrix
newMat = zeros(m,n,z*2);

%assign old matrix values into the new matrix
newMat(:,:,1:2:end) = mat;
newMat(:,:,2:2:end) = mat;
```

Comment: On your last two lines, don''t you mean: `newMat(:,:,1:2:end) = mat`?

Comment: @Suever - definitely - that's what I meant :) thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Matlab 2015a or newer you can use [`repelem`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
N = 2; %// number of times to repeat
result = repelem(mat, 1, 1, N); %// repeat N times along 3rd dim
```

For older Matlab versions you can do it manually as follows:

```
N = 2; %// number of times to repeat
ind = ceil(1/N:1/N:size(mat,3)); %// build index with repetitions
result = mat(:,:,ind); %// apply index along desired dim
```

Example:

```
>> %// Data
>> mat = randi(9,2,4,2)
mat(:,:,1) =
     5     8     9     2
     7     3     1     5
mat(:,:,2) =
     5     7     1     1
     1     8     8     2

>> %// First approach
>> N = 2;
>> result = repelem(mat, 1, 1, N)
result(:,:,1) =
     5     8     9     2
     7     3     1     5
result(:,:,2) =
     5     8     9     2
     7     3     1     5
result(:,:,3) =
     5     7     1     1
     1     8     8     2
result(:,:,4) =
     5     7     1     1
     1     8     8     2

>> %// Second approach
>> N = 2;
>> ind = ceil(1/N:1/N:size(mat,3));
>> result = mat(:,:,ind)
result(:,:,1) =
     5     8     9     2
     7     3     1     5
result(:,:,2) =
     5     8     9     2
     7     3     1     5
result(:,:,3) =
     5     7     1     1
     1     8     8     2
result(:,:,4) =
     5     7     1     1
     1     8     8     2
```